# Convert numbers to time?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a slick way to convert simple numbers (Army time included) to a time format (am, pm format)? I can do the tedious approach, but I was just wondering if there was another way

0800 => 8:00 am

2317 => 11:17 pm

Comment: What do you mean by 'the tedious approach'? DateTime.ParseExact() with a custom format provider?

Comment: var time = DateTime.ParseExact("0800", "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("0800", "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string timestring = dt.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for format codes.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this points you in the right direction:

```
    string time = "0800";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0}:{1}", time.Substring(0, 2), time.Substring(2, 2)), "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:h:mm tt}", dt));

    time = "2345";
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0}:{1}", time.Substring(0, 2), time.Substring(2, 2)), "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:h:mm tt}", dt));
```

Comment: Why do you reformat the string to HH:mm format and not user directly HHmm format ?

Comment: Good question.  Because I wrote it fast and didn't think about that.  :)

Comment: @Robaticus what if the input time was "23" (as 00:23)? Then your code would throw exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) with the format string you want.

If you can accept several formats then you'll need to call each in turn until you find the one that matches - which I assume is what you mean by "the tedious approach".