# Convert 6 digits number to Time with AM / PM

Tags: c#, datetime

i have to show time like as example 09:40 A.M. and as a input i have value like `150000`
so this way i try to convert int to time like below way

```
string s = DateTime.ParseExact("150000", "HHmm", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

but unfortunately i am getting error. so guide me how can i convert integer to time with `HH:MM AM/PM`

this is the xml where date & time included in separate tag like this way

```
<tnt:Arrival>
<tnt:Date>20140715</tnt:Date>
<tnt:Time>233000</tnt:Time>
</tnt:Arrival>
```

so i need to show time from

> tnt:Time tag

and display like 03:20 A.M. `HH:MM AM/PM`. so guide me. thanks

now i got clue which now works. here is the solution

```
string fromTimeString = DateTime.FromOADate(150000).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

the above code return `12:00 AM` i guess i am on right track and issue is solved. thanks

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: How do you get from `150000` to `9:40 AM`? `3:00 PM` I'd understand...

Comment: Have you forgotten ss in your time format?

Comment: i edit my question for better clarification.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why 150000 would equal 9:40 AM is some weird case with `StopWatch` Frequency ticks. This Frequency differs depending on the underlying timing mechanism. Looking at your example, it seems you only need to add ss, so `HHmmss` for your `ParseExact`

Comment: i am not saying 9:40 that was just a example. 150000 could be 03:20 or 10:50 AM anyhthing

Comment: @Thomas - Well, no. `150000` could not be "anything". If `150000` is `3:00 PM` and `233000` is `11:30 PM`, then, as @djechelon and @Davio already pointed out, you probably want to use `DateTime.ParseExact("150000", "HHmmss", [...])`.

Comment: here i edited my question and i use FromOADate() function to get time and it is working now. so plzz have look at my answer and tell me does it right wrong. thanks

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the question. What is the units of measure of the `150000` value? Seconds since a particular date? How can you possibly go from a unit-less number to a specific time?

Comment: Wait, so is the question answered?

Comment: yea... it seems to be answered

Comment: @Thomas - Funny... `DateTime.FromOADate(233000).ToString("hh:mm tt");` also returns `12:00 AM` ... because that means you want the time from (midnight, december 30 1899) + 233000 *days*. so it will *always* return `12:00 PM` Please read [DateTime.FromOADate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) for further information.

Comment: thanks i was wrongly use FromOADate() function because i am not aware of usage of FromOADate() func.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023188/convert-numbers-to-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `InvariantCulture` to make sure we have `AM/PM` suffixes.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo c = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string s = DateTime.ParseExact("233000", "HHmmss", c).ToString("h:mm tt", c);
```

Comment: i use this code string fromTimeString = DateTime.FromOADate(150000).ToString("hh:mm tt"); and this return 12:00 A.M. is it right or not?

Comment: It is not wrong, but you have to keep in mind it only works if the current culture of the system it runs on is set to something which has AM/PM suffixes. If you were to run your code on a Dutch system, you won't get AM/PM in your string.

Comment: here u use CultureInfo("en-GB") but if i use this  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture then what will be difference in result? please tell me what is the meaning of InvariantCulture ??

Comment: The `InvariantCulture` is a default English culture without any specific region (therefore it is stable and hardly changes over time) and outputs `AM/PM`.

Comment: [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

Comment: InvariantCulture always output `AM/PM` when it run on dutch pc ??

Comment: Yes, I have a Dutch system and it shows `AM/PM` with the `InvariantCulture`

Comment: so we can write the code like ystem.Globalization.CultureInfo c = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string s = DateTime.ParseExact("233000", "HHmmss", c).ToString("h:mm tt"); ?

Comment: Yep, that should work, but if your data is an OLE Date, use `DateTime.FromOADate` as you were doing and only use the `culture` for the `ToString` method. I'll edit my answer to reflect the comments. I fear `FromOADate` is not correct however as it will always give you `12:00`