# Converting multiple integer values to a DateTime

Tags: c#

I have some int values such as hour and minute. I would like to use these values to create a DateTime format so I can check whether the current time of the computer is after a predefined time.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated as I have looked and found nothing so far.

Comment: The constructor does exactly this, surely?

Comment: Have you encountered a problem? Did you try something? If you just type `new DateTime(` Intellisense will kick in and display the available constructors

Comment: Are you interesed in dates or times? You can represent a time span with TimeSpan. DateTime must have a year/month/date part

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't realize it worked this way, haven't been coding for long. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm interested in the time.

Comment: @Conor you can use `DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(hours, minutes,seconds))` to get a value you can check against `DateTime.Now` directly. Added as answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh wow, thanks. That actually makes much more sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert numbers to time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023188/convert-numbers-to-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness' sake, you can add the time part to `DateTime.Today` :

```
DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(hours,minutes,seconds));
```

This makes the intention of the code clearer:

```
var target=DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(hours,minutes,seconds));
if (target>DateTime.Now) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried one of the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx) constructors:

```
public DateTime(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int minute,
    int second
)
```

So you can do something like:

```
var h = 12;
var m = 34;
var s = 10;
var example = new DateTime(2016,6,22,h,m,s);
```

Comment: No I haven't, thanks for the reply. I will test this now and get back to you :)

Comment: Just tried this and it worked, thanks a lot! I'm new to coding so didn't actually realize it was this simple.

Answer (score 1):

create a date time object , with only hours, minute, second field using your custom values

```
var myDate= new DateTime (DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, hours, minute, second);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(timeAsInt, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```