# VB.net Converting integer to desired format

Tags: vb.net

**Code**

```
myObject.TotalTime = 745

Dim test As Integer = Integer.Parse(myObject.TotalTime)

Dim test2 As String = test.ToString("00:00:00")
```

*Desired result* : 7:45:00

*Current result* : "00:07:45"

anyone knows a more sufficient way to convert this? like 2lines of code or even 1 line with a use of casting and such if only possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` method and use `h:mm:ss` format string like this:

```
myObject.TotalTime = 745
Dim test As Integer = Integer.Parse(myObject.TotalTime)

' since it may contains 4 digits (e.g. 1000),
' use 4 digits for parsing instead of 3
Dim test1 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(test.ToString("0000"), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Dim test2 As String = test1.ToString("h:mm:ss")
```

Result: `7:45:00`

Working example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L5Noas)

Related issue: [Convert numbers to time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023188/convert-numbers-to-time)